# Meaning of 'nicht sehr gut'?

Tags: phrase, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of 'nicht sehr gut'?  I've heard it variously translated as 'not so good', 'not 100%', 'not very good', and 'not very well'.  Does its meaning change when describing a person as opposed to an object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, this is a euphemism meaning that it is bad.

I don't think that the usage differs a lot from English:

> The service was not very good.
>
> He's not very good at baseball.

And in both languages you can change the meaning by stressing "very" or "sehr".

> He may not be **very** good at baseball, but he is still a solid member of the team.
>
> Er ist vielleicht nicht **sehr** gut im Baseballspielen, aber er ist dennoch ein verläßliches Teammitglied.

Comment: you could even say *not good at all*

Comment: Right, but as well as indicating skill or achievement, it can also indicate health?  As in, the English equivalent would be 'he is **not very well**'?

Comment: @Jez: No: "He is not very well" -> "Es geht ihm nicht sehr gut."

Comment: Yes, but *nicht sehr gut* is still used in that description, that's my point.

Comment: This figure of speech is called [Litotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes).

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the phrase depends on the context, for example:

> "Wie ging die Klassenarbeit in der Schule?" - "Nicht sehr gut"
>
> "Wie geht es dir heute nach dem Unfall?" - "Es geht mir nicht sehr gut."

These examples can be translated as "**not so good**".

The following sentence

> Viele Fußballer können nicht sehr gut singen.

could be translated to

> Many football players are **not very good** at singing.

Answer (score 1):

Its meaning can be translated with *not so good*. As in

> He is sleeping because his health status is not so good.

You could find other translations, but it basically means that something or someone could be or do better.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of school it could mean getting a "2" (good) instead of a "1" (very good).
Generally it implicates that one could have done better.